# What is the difference between independent subspace analysis and independent component analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, independent-component-analysis

What is the difference between independent subspace analysis (ISA) and independent component analysis (ICA)?

Comment: The search for "independent space analysis" [yields only 7 results on Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.pt/scholar?hl=en&q="independent+space+analysis") and these look mostly irrelevant; are you sure this term really exists?

Comment: yes, I did! I think it's pretty new. I had this word in the paper "Learning hierarchical invariant spatio-temporal features for action recognition.", but I don't quite understand what exactly it is.

Comment: Aha, so it is "independent **SUBSPACE** analysis"! Now I get 1000+ results on Google Scholar.

Comment: great! Ya, independent subspace analysis.